# Firebase data lost when updating document from multiple devices at same time

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a angular web app for playing games.

Users can create rooms to which an unlimited number of players can join.

Rooms are saved as documents in firestore. Users and their states are saved in a array.
Here is a simplyfied version of my classes:

```js
export class Room {
   roomName: string;
   players: Player[];
}

export class Player {
   id: string;
   state: number;
}
```

When a user joins a room, they add a entry to the `players` array.

The problem is, when two users join a room simultaneously, the second user overwrites the changes from the first user.

Here is an example:

- Admin creates Room -> Admin is saved to players array
- User 2 and 3 join the Room -> Both load the current room, in which only one player is saved.
- Each client adds the user entry to the array of players in the currently loaded room
- Update statements are sent
- Now in the first update the Admin and User 2 are saved in the players array
- In the second update the Admin and User 3 are saved in the array -> User 2 didn't not join

Is there a way to save the data in such a way, that this can't happen? Maybe don't save user in an array and only update a specific field of the document.

I want to avoid using documents for each user because i think it is more price and performance efficient, when using only one document for a room. So i don't have to load a single document for each user.

Comment: Im affraid your Players array should be swtiched to a Firestore Collection, yes, it will be more complicated to work in that way and you cannot load nested collections with firestore during their parent loading, by a single request i mean. But if you are familiar with RxJs - this lib can simplify your life a lot https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxfire.

Here is an example about its usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492280/firestore-rxfire-query-collection-then-subscribe-to-array-of-sub-observables

Comment: It should be possible to do this atomically with [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) and/or [`array-union`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array), but it's impossible to say why you're having problems without seeing the [minimal code with which we can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is right. ArrayUnion should handle this. It would allow you update the array at the same time with different values. NB: Use **update** method (not set) with ArrayUnion, e.g `firestore.doc('col/doc').update({'players': admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion('playerId')});`. Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found a solution to the problem.

As described in my post, i didn't like the idea of a collection for players because of price and performance reasons.
The suggestion to use `arrayUnion()` and `arrayRemove()` also did not satisfy me because that way i would not be able to update a entry with one request (as i understood).

Soooo i used a different approach. Instead of saving the players in a array i saved them in a players object as simple objects like so:

```js
export class Room {
  players: {
    [key: string]: Player;
  };
}
```

so my rooms would look like that:

```js
}
  myId: {
    id: "myId",
    state: 1
  },
  myId2: {
    id: "myId2",
    state: 0
  }
}
```

That way i was able to directly edit the field where the player is saved like so:

```js
  updateField(roomId: string, player: Player) {
    return updateDoc(doc(this.firestore, `room/${roomId}`), {
      [`infos.players.${player.id}`]: player
    });
  }
```